# Unable to call get instance of Windows Azure Cache

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage, azure-worker-roles

Trying to create a new Dedicated Cache Role in Windows Azure but get the `NotSupportedException: This operation is not supported by the cache` exception every time I run this code. As a summary, here is what I've done...

I construct the cache using the following code, and the exception occures as soon as I call `GetCache(string)`:

```
_dataCacheFactory = new DataCacheFactory();
_cache = _dataCacheFactory.GetCache(cacheName);
```

Additionally, I've added the appropriate `<dataCacheClients>` configuration section and references to the following assemblies (*All reference the assemblies in `Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Azure\.NET SDK\2012-06\ref`*):

- Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.AzureClientHelper
- Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.AzureCommon
- Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.Client
- Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.Core
- Microsoft.Web.DistributedCache

I have also setup the Cache Worker Role in the Azure project.

As far as I can tell I've followed all the MSDN documentation, can anyone suggest what may be wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing you're trying to get a named cache, which is [not supported](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg278350.aspx) in Azure Shared Caching. Instead of `_dataCacheFactory.GetCache(cacheName)`, try using `_dataCacheFactory.GetDefaultCache()`.

Comment: I am not sure I understand "Shared" Caching... I will look that up. What do I need to do to support "Named" Caches?

Comment: "Shared" caching is the Azure Appfabric Caching that's been around for about 18 months. I haven't heard of any plans to support named caches there. The other kind of caching is the Caching Preview that was just announced a couple of weeks ago. That's a private cache. I believe you can do named caches there. Depending on your use case, it may be a more suitable option. 
https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/how-to-guides/cache/

Comment: Thanks... This led to the solution. I had to use the `DataCacheFactory(DataCacheFactoryConfiguration)` constructor overload to target a named configuration. Then I was able to use the `GetDefaultCache()` method which essentially targeted a named instance associated to that factory.

Answer (score 2):

When you you are using [Windows Azure Cache (Dedicated and Co-located Cache)](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/how-to-guides/cache/) you  must use the references located below (This is released as preview):

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Azure\.NET SDK\2012-06\ref\CachingPreview
```

Also when you are using [Windows Azure Shared Cache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg278356.aspx) then you should use references located below:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Azure\.NET SDK\2012-06\ref\
```

The difference between **Windows Azure Cache (Dedicated and Co-located Cache)** and **Windows Azure Shared Cache** is that the first one resides in your virtual machine and shared between instances by creating a cumulative shared cache, while the second one is located outside your Virtual Machines (in Windows Azure you configure it from Windows Azure Management Portal) and all instances are connecting this cache over a network pipe.